# CPU Usage : top and mpstat show different results

Tags: server, nginx, php-fpm

`top` and `mpstat` show different results.

`top`:

```
%Cpu(s): 10.9 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.2 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st

31426 www-data  20   0  309088  21276  14600 S  22.3  0.1   0:07.36 php-fpm: pool www
31431 www-data  20   0  308980  21232  14568 S  22.3  0.1   0:01.69 php-fpm: pool www
31423 www-data  20   0  308992  21376  14664 S  21.6  0.1   0:08.38 php-fpm: pool www
31437 www-data  20   0  308988  21224  14568 R  20.9  0.1   0:00.66 php-fpm: pool www
```

and `mpstat`:

```
04:05:29 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
04:05:29 PM  all    1.06    0.00    0.29    0.02    0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.57
04:05:29 PM    0    0.81    0.00    0.32    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.84
04:05:29 PM    1    1.40    0.00    0.37    0.02    0.00    0.07    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.14
04:05:29 PM    2    1.39    0.00    0.36    0.02    0.00    0.07    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.16
04:05:29 PM    3    1.35    0.00    0.35    0.02    0.00    0.07    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.21
04:05:29 PM    4    0.98    0.00    0.25    0.01    0.00    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.68
04:05:29 PM    5    0.86    0.00    0.22    0.01    0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.85
04:05:29 PM    6    0.81    0.00    0.21    0.02    0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.90
04:05:29 PM    7    0.87    0.00    0.22    0.02    0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.83
```

Is the server overloaded already?

Comment: Not at 85.2% idle

Comment: In top command, php-fpm is using 22.3, 22.3, 21.6 and 20.9 cpu. what does it mean?

Comment: 100% means 1 CPU is fully used. So what you see for php-fpm is 87.1% of one CPU out of 8 i.e. less than 11% of your total CPU power.

Comment: If you press the number 1 in top it will give you a breakdown of CPU usage per CPU. Top displays a single CPU by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`top`:

100% means 1 CPU is fully used. So what you see for php-fpm is 87.1% of one CPU out of 8 i.e. less than 11% of your total CPU power.

`mpstat`:

If you do not give an interval to mpstat it gives you the average CPU utilization since startup.
`mpstat -P ALL 2 5` gives you five results of 2-second-intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Not at 85.2% idle. By default, top displays a single cpu. Press "1" to display a breakdown of CPU usage per CPU.